# Reading Pixmap into IODev in Qt & Ruby

Tags: ruby, qt, qt4

I want to get the image data from an image in memory.

According to the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#save-2), I should be able to call `PixMap.save` with an IODevice, after which I can read the data from the IODevice.

The problem is that this does not seem to happen, and `save` returns `false`. After that, I still cannot access anything from the IODevice.

I am doing the following:

```
require 'Qt'
app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
pixmap = Qt::Pixmap.new("samples/CIMG0485.JPG")
iodev = Qt::IODevice.new
pixmap.save(iodev)            # returns false, no change to iodev
pixmap.save("other_file.jpg") # returns true, file saved
```

Comment: I think you need to use a QBuffer (a subclass of IODevice) and open it in write mode

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it made me hopeful. `iodev.open(Qt::IODevice::WriteOnly)` returns true, but the call to save returns false leaving the Buffer unchanged :-(